# How to properly model an linear power supply with LDO in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, ldo, linear-regulator

I've build the following linear power supply:

[image]

Before building it I tried to model it in LTspice. I couldn't find an LTspice model of L4941BV LDO ([datasheet [PDF]](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/stmicroelectronics/2142.pdf)) or a suitable replacement. Thus I used the following "naive" model:

[image]

R1, R2, L1 and L2 are measured resistance and inductance of a transformer windings. V1 is 50Hz, amplitude: 310 V. Here is Vout:

[image]

My idea was following. Let's say that all extra voltage turns into heat, and also account for ~10 mA quiescent current  of LDO itself. In other words assume that this circuit's output power is ~0.95W.

Naturally this model turns out to be inadequate. It predicts PF 0.442 and efficiency 32%. The real device can produce up to 217 mA before a noticeable ripple (60 mV) will be observed. Under these circumstances it's measured PF is 0.925, consumed power - 2.75 W and efficiency - about 39.5%.

I tried to play with values used in the model but didn't come even close to observed PF and efficiency. Thus it looks like a less naive model is required.

The problem is I have no clue how to make an accurate model of an LDO. Could you please explain how it can be done or at least suggest some literature on the subject.

Comment: I'm quite confused here, what you have built is not even near an LDO, it's not regulating anything at all, just a plain old unregulated AC-DC converter. Did you forget to show your "naive" version?

Comment: Maybe replace the current sink with a ~30 ohm resistor and see if you can get the PF and voltages to agree with reality. Speaking of reality,  in reality you would want a lot more voltage at the input of the regulator to account for mains variations. That particular regulator is a lateral PNP type that has an Iq spike near dropout, though not as severe as some, so it’s not as simple to accurately model as, say, a modern CMOS type.

Comment: You can use "NCP1117ST50T3G" spice model.Its output voltage 5V fixed like L4941BV and 1A.  you can find model in the link .https://www.mouser.com.tr/ProductDetail/ON-Semiconductor/NCP1117ST50T3G?qs=Gev%252BmEvV0ib6dijy6U0dhQ==

Comment: @GuneyBoss The LM1117 types have much higher (like 5x higher) dropout voltage than the OP's regulator. They're really semi-LDO types.

Comment: Are you looking for a generic, simple LDO like a NPN and  Zener, or more complex ones with current and voltage limiting, or a model for a 7805 for example, or a simple behavioural approach?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  As to NCP111's datasheet,  dropout voltage is 1.07V at 800mA LM1117's 1.2V at the same current level. Am I missing something or Am I misunderstood?

Comment: @GuneyBoss At OP's 200mA operating current, the typical dropout of the NCP1117 is about 950mV compared to 150mV for the L4941.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to understand how LDOs work and how to simulate them i suggest much more reading. https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/low-dropout-regulators.html is a decent start and I'm certain you could find a lot more.

Alternatively you could use a SPICE model of a LDO IC that is close to the one you have. You can find some at :
https://www.pspice.com/models/rohm

Comment: I guess I didn't explain the situation well enough. LDO was used next to the circuit shown, on OUT. I edited the text accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Can you show what you used as an LDO then ?

Comment: I will upload a complete schematic shortly.

Comment: The question was updated.